# execute JAR file using a specific version of the JRE

Tags: java, jar, command-line-arguments

My JRE version is 1.8.0_77 but I want to run a JAR file with an older version of the JRE to see if the JAR will work on an older version of the JRE.

Is there a special command line option that I can add to the `java` command to do this, or do I have to download an older version of the JRE to do this?

I already looked at the `java -h` output...it seems like the answer is probably that I will have to download an older version of the JRE to do this...but I wanted to ask anyway...just in case.

Thanks!

Comment: Just run by explicitly stating the path to Java Executable

Comment: What @AndrewL. said `"PATH TO JAVA.exe" -jar Jarfile.jar`

Comment: So I will need to download an older version of the JRE? I can't add a special command line option to my java 8's java command to make it pretend its an older version of the JRE?

Comment: Yeah. The system won't know what Java 7 or lower is if you don't have it installed :^)

Comment: ah, okay. thanks for the help!!! :) @AndrewL. and 3kings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you will need to download and install older version(which you want to test with). Just run it in detailed path like:

```
/path/to/older/java.exe -jar whatever.jar
```

If you are using any IDE, it always provides the utility that run your code in custom ways: run in specific JRE, with different arguments and so on. Just make up a run task of your purpose.