# How do I install an earlier version of Java for testing Windows app?

Tags: java, windows, installation, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans to develop a Windows app that needs to send email. It works when run from Netbeans(NB), but not outside. Specifically, running the created .jar fails to connect. I think the is the default NB Java version is **jdk1.8.0_131** (presumably because that was the current JDK when I originally installed NB and began my app development), while Windows C:\Program Files\Java shows jdk1.8.0_131 and jre1.8.0_291. To test this, I'd like to run my NB created .jar file using jre1.8.0_131.

The selected answer to [execute JAR file using a specific version of the JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023806/execute-jar-file-using-a-specific-version-of-the-jre) says I have to download and install "download and install older version." I've mad several attempts to do the latter, but have yet to find the exact download among the myriad of items at Oracle's site. I'm running Windows 10 Pro.

Any guidance gratefully accepted.

Comment: If you look for the exact page to download old version then here you are
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/oracle-java-archive-downloads.html
dont forget to add the installation folder to the System path

Comment: I think you are coming at this from the wrong angle. Rather than trying to revert to update 131, forget about it and do everything using update 291. To achieve this: [1] Download/install JDK update 291, then set the NetBeans default platform to use update 291 [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262185/2985643). [2] Restart NetBeans to run on update 291. [3] Rebuild your app using update 291. [4] Test your "291" app. This approach allows you to run with all the latest security patches and bug fixes for Java, and you don't need to worry about an obsolete release.

Comment: Thx Adam. I see Offline Windows x86 jre-8u131-windows-x64.exe,  Windows x86 jre-8u131-windowsx64.tar.gz, an several for i586. My guess is I need Offline Windows x86 jre-8u131-windows-x64.exe. Is that right?

Comment: Thx, Skomisa. What troubles me with that is that my app DOES run when launched from NB using 131. It DOESN'T run outside NB and the only difference is the JRE 291. It seems to me that if I switched to JRE 291 in NB it wouldn't run at all. Then I'd have to figure out why and fix it which might take a long time. The app schedules judging for car shows, in particular at one in late September. So it must be running one way or another in a couple weeks. Afterwards, I can go back and do it the right way.

Comment: @EdS [1] OK, but it literally only takes two minutes to try what I suggested, and it's trivial to revert to your current configuration if things don't work out. [2] Your claim that _"the only difference is the JRE 291"_ isn't correct. There are potentially lots of environmental differences between running an app within NetBeans and outside of NetBeans. [3] FYI, I just tried to install 131 from an existing download on my machine, and Oracle's installer wouldn't do it. Your call, but I think it's dangerous to be using 131 at all. [4] Consider posting a separate question on your connect problem.

Comment: Skomisa, Trying to follow your appreciated advice, but no joy yet, I chose to use 301 since it's latest. Ran the installer and found it was put in Looks like it was put in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\. Also About Java now shows Version 8 Update 301 (1.8.0_301-b09). However, when I Open the NB Platform Manager and click Add Platform there's no new JDK so I can't add 301.  So, I'm dead in the water. What am I missing? Don't know if you're a NB user...

Comment: @EdS You can explicitly specify 301 as the default platform by editing the configuration file **netbeans.conf**, providing the full path to the 301 update in that file. Follow the link in item _[1]_ in my initial comment above for full details on what to do. After saving your changes and restarting NetBeans, verify that **Help > About** shows 301. Then rebuild and retest your app inside and outside of NetBeans.

Comment: @Eds As an unrelated matter, please note that when you are replying to someone in a comment, be sure to prefix their username with `@` so that they receive a notification for your comment. (e.g. `@skomisa` rather than just `skomisa`).

Comment: RE: @username-- Got it.

Comment: @skomisa. Hate to reveal my ignorance even more, but I've never heard of netbeans.conf. The only way I know of to do what you suggest is the Platform Manager. All one can do there that changes things, to my knowledge, is Add a Platform or edit Sources. As  I said before I've not been able to do an Add, and it seems that all one can do with sources is change the source for the selected Platform. About shows 131.

Comment: @EdS **netbeans.conf** is just a simple text file containing name/value pairs, where comment lines start with a `#`. Locate it within the **etc** directory of your NetBeans installation and open it in any text editor. Then specify the path to your 301 installation. You will be adding something similar to this **netbeans_jdkhome="C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_301"** though obviously your path will probably differ. Save that change to **netbeans.conf** and restart NetBeans. Then **Help > About** should show 301 instead of 131. (Be sure to specify the path correctly or NetBeans won't start!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236782/discussion-between-ed-s-and-skomisa).

Comment: @EdS Just FYI, please note that _"perhaps using remote access to my Windows 10 computer to show me exactly how. Telephone or Zoom with screen sharing might work"_ is not how things are done here. While that might help you, it won't help anyone else who faces the same problem, so the focus on SO should only be on high quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a change of Oracle's licences, you can't download older versions of Oracle's java without an Oracle account.
That being said, you probably want to take a look at [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/) or [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html) for older java versions.

Comment: Thanks, Mubin. I have an Oracle account. I can see many, many legacy downloads, but don't know which one :-( I'll take alook at the two other sources you mention.

Answer (score 0):

To start with :

- Using any of the older releases form archive is a potential security
  risk.
- The specific root cause of the real problem 'works with IDE not with jar' may not necessarily be with the major/minor version itself

But since the question you have posted is about how to install older version, my answer would be:

1. You should first confirm the specific version of Java SE you need. If it's an older version, that should probably be **Java 6**, **Java 7** or **Java 8**. If you have already faced an issue, you logs would generally show errors pertaining to a version. If yes, cross check with this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2) for details.
2. Go to this [Java Archive](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/oracle-java-archive-downloads.html) link.
3. Good to Sign-in at this point or create an account
4. You will find sections for Java SE, Java EE, Java ME and Java FX. The default **Java SE** is the one you probably need
5. Click on the link for the specific version e.g. **Java SE 8**
6. That page will show you a list of sections ordered in this form

   1. Ordered by latest update release number
   2. Type (JDK, JRE or Server JRE)
7. Select the latest on the top with section name starting Java SE Development Kit. E.g. for Java SE 8 search for '**Java SE Development Kit 8u**'
8. In this section select the download for the specific OS version. E.g. **Windows x64**

**Find JDK installation path :**

On windows, if you have installed too many JRE/JDK installations and you are unware of the location :

1. Click Windows key + X, then I
2. Copy paste text : `Get-Childitem –Path C:\ -Include javac.exe -Filter javac.exe -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`
3. Using judgement or even date, note the directory that contains the version number you have installed

**Make changes how your application runs :**

**Option 1 :**

Right click My computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Below variables to be modified similar to :

- `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xxx`
- `JDK_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xxx`
- Append a `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the `PATH` variable as well
- Run

**Option 2 :**

- Install older version of the JDK on a separate machine and copy the folder onto your new hosted machine.
- If you jar name is ed.jar and Main class is com.ed.Main then use direct call similar to below :

  - `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaw -cp ed.jar com.ed.Main`
  - OR `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaw -jar ed.jar`

Comment: Thx @RajeevSreedharan. This seems to be the same as suggested in an earlier answer. Doesn't help me because even though I've selected the JDK, when installed I seem to have only the corresponding JRE and the NetBeans Platform Manager allows only allows me to JDK Add a JDK.

Comment: @EdS I doubt that, JDK installer does install JDK which has JRE binaries included. It would be one hell of an oversight otherwise worldwide, wouldn't it? If you are unsure of the location you have installed, search for a javac.exe from your windows search. Next in the netbeans.conf add this path to JDK instead of any other JRE you were referring earlier.

Comment: @Eds Initially I faced the same problem as you: only the JRE for 131 was installed, even though I had definitely downloaded the JDK for 131. See my comment in the OP: "_I just tried to install 131 from an existing download on my machine, and Oracle's installer wouldn't do it_". However, I think that was because I had a more recent update of JDK 8 already installed. Unfortunately the installer gives no warning in this scenario. The solution that worked for me (as given in my answer) was to ensure that no instance of JDK 8 was already installed before installing update 131.

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan Re _"It would be one hell of an oversight otherwise worldwide"_ is an unhelpful generalization that misses the point. There IS an oversight in the installation process, when installing JDK 8 and a more recent update is already installed, and that is the unusual scenario that the OP encountered. Arguing that the installer must always work simply because many people have used it successfully is illogical.

Comment: @EdS why not just directly call your jar using the older JDK you seem to have already installed. A sample in option-2

Comment: @skomisa To be clear, its impossible to have oversight of that kind. A JDK installer cannot install a JRE by mistake. It installs a JDK which naturally has JRE binaries included. Bombarding with an essay of comments about version, would not make sense in any better way.

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan Re _"its impossible to have oversight of that kind"_,  you are completely wrong. Both the OP and I had that issue when installing an update for JDK 8 that is older than an existing installed update. It is not an "oversight" or "mistake"; it is deliberate. The issue isn't that the installer only installs the JRE, but that it gives the user no feedback on why it is doing that. Perhaps you should attempt to actually solve the OP's problem rather than offering theoretical solutions. If you did that you would also see that only the JRE gets installed.

Answer (score 0):

I got NetBeans 12.4 running on JDK 8 update 131 on Windows 10 as follows:

- First note that there are issues with the use of Firefox for this process, so use a non-Mozilla browser such as Chrome or Edge.
- Update 131 is a very old release, and (I think) is only available from Oracle via their [Java downloads](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html). You will need an Oracle Account (rather than a Cloud Account) to download, so create one now if necessary. Otherwise log in to your Oracle Account by clicking the *View Accounts* button at the top of the page.
- Oracle's installer gets upset and confused if you have some higher update of JDK 8 already installed, so the first thing I did was to remove it through **Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a program**. Optionally delete any remaining JDK installation files from disk as well, though that is not essential.
- Go to Oracle's web page for downloading old updates of JDK 8 and JRE 8: It's a very long web page titled "[*Java SE 8 Archive Downloads (JDK 8u202 and earlier)*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html)".
- To save scrolling, search in the browser for the text "*131*". You should land exactly where you need to be within the page, on a line titled "*Java SE Development Kit 8u131*". Scroll down just a few lines to the line for your hardware and O/S combination. In my case this was "*Windows x64*".
- Click the link for the download file specified to the right on that line. In my case it was named **jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe**. The browser should download the file, although if you haven't yet logged in to your Oracle account you will be prompted to do so. As long as your credentials are valid the download will still work.
- Since you are using Windows, in File Explorer locate the downloaded file in your browser's *download* folder. In my case the size of the downloaded file was 207,649,848 bytes.
- Double click the file to execute it, and run the JDK installer. By default the installer will install the JDK to one of the *Program Files* directories on Windows, but you can specify an alternative directory if you prefer. If all goes well the install of update 131 of JDK 8 should work, and you will see this screen:

  [image: installerSuccess]
- Next, in NetBeans 12.4 open **Tools > Java Platforms** and click the **Add Platform...** button to add JDK 8 update 131. It should be shown as a new platform, though not the default one:

  [image: JavaPlatforms]
- At this point, if you don't want or need JDK 8 update 131 to be your default platform (meaning it is the platform that NetBeans itself runs on), you are finished. Otherwise, follow the remaining four steps below.
- Next, edit **netbeans.conf** to make JDK 8 update 131 the default platform. Add a line similar to the one below, but specifying your appropriate path:

  **netbeans_jdkhome="C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_131"**
- If there are any other lines in the file starting with **netbeans_jdkhome** comment them out with a leading **#**.
- Save the file and restart NetBeans.
- From **Help > About** you should see that JDK 8 update 131 is now the default platform:

  [image: HelpAbout]

Comment: I've not had time to follow this for awhile. Haven't tried it yet, but it is certainly thorough and the included screenshots demonstrate that it works at lease for NB 12.4 . Thanks you!

Comment: @EdS OK. I think the crucial point is that any more recent update of JDK 8 should be uninstalled before attempting to install 131. It's unfortunate the installer doesn't clearly explain what it is doing, and why.

Comment: My app now works both from within Netbeans and in Windows using 131 as NB default and 131 set as the Windows JRE version. Note that I  downloaded jre 131 separately since my Inno Setup script expects the jre. Sends the emails just fine. Much appreciate your help, and that of others.

Comment: BTW, I'll switch to the latest Java version after using the app in early October.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if you never installed Java 7 or if you don't have an Oracle account.
Oracle said that [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/java_7.html).